# os.path.join wont except it and unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python, path, directory, file-handling

```
character = open(os.path.join(\\Fantasy Board Game\\Character Sheets - ), namecharacter + '.txt', 'wt')
```

This code gives 'unexpected character after line continuation character'

```
character = open(os.path.join("\\Fantasy Board Game\\Character Sheets - "), namecharacter + '.txt', 'wt')
```

This code gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Fantasy Board Game\Game Program\DandD style game.py", line 150, in <module>
    character = open(os.path.join("\\Fantasy Board Game\\Character Sheets - "), namecharacter + '.txt', 'wt')
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Comment: Accept vs except... but more importantly... you kind of have two questions here... the first one is fairly easy (you don't have quotes around your file path, and \ is used as a line continuation character).  The second one DeepSpace appears to have addreesed in his answer (basically... you're doing open(filepath, something, "wt") instead of the intended open(filepath, "wt") ... and open's optional 3rd argument is buffer which is an integer)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `)`, line should be:

```
character = open(os.path.join("\\Fantasy Board Game\\Character Sheets - ",
                                namecharacter + '.txt'), 'wt')
```

Comment: Now they don't match.

Comment: Had a mistake myself, I fixed my answer

Comment: I'm trying to create a file called namecharacter + ".txt". Its saying thi isn't the right code. It can find that directory. is this correct?